# Merge Sort Implementation in Python

Tags: python

```
def merge_sort(arr):
    arr1 = []
    arr2 = []
    mid = int(len(arr)/2)
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return arr
    elif len(arr) > 2:
        arr1 = arr[0:mid]
        arr2 = arr[mid:len(arr)]
        return [merge_sort(arr1), merge_sort(arr2)]
    elif len(arr) == 2:
        if arr[0]>arr[1]:
            temp = arr[0]
            arr[0] = arr[1]
            arr[1] = temp
        return arr
```

I had written this function which divides a list recursively into half till it's length becomes at least 1 or 2.

If the length of the list becomes:

1. the list is returned as it is while if the length of the list becomes
2. the elements of list are swapped such that they get arranged in ascending order and the list is returned.

The problem is that after this code runs, the output is in the form of list of lists and merging them is appearing to be a tuff job.

The code generates following output for the given call:

```
merge_sort([5,4,1,8,7,2,6,3,9])
```

Output:

```
[[[4, 5], [1, 8]], [[2, 7], [[6], [3, 9]]]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Merge Sort Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) you must have a `merge` function so that in each step of merging, you sort two small parts. The problem is that you are just swapping two numbers when arrays size is 2.

```
def merge(arr1,arr2):
    it1 = 0
    it2 = 0
    ret = []
    while it1 < len(arr1) or it2 < len(arr2):
        if it1 == len(arr1):
            ret.append(arr2[it2])
            it2+=1
        elif it2 == len(arr2):
            ret.append(arr1[it1])
            it1+=1
        else:
            if arr1[it1] > arr2[it2]:
                ret.append(arr2[it2])
                it2+=1
            else:
                ret.append(arr1[it1])
                it1+=1
    return ret



def merge_sort(arr):
    arr1 = []
    arr2 = []
    mid = int(len(arr)/2)
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return arr
    elif len(arr) > 2:
        arr1 = arr[0:mid]
        arr2 = arr[mid:len(arr)]
        return merge(merge_sort(arr1), merge_sort(arr2))
    elif len(arr) == 2:
        if arr[0]>arr[1]:
            temp = arr[0]
            arr[0] = arr[1]
            arr[1] = temp
    return arr
```

PS. I just edited your code with some small changes. You can write Merge Sort Algorithm in a better way and more neatly.